# How to implement Data tables using Angular 2.0?

Tags: angular

I want to implement data table using Angular2.0 and needed options like paging,sorting, filtering. Please help

Comment: Have you tried the ng2-table https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-table

Comment: Go through this [How to Ask ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take a tour before posting a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of 3rd party libraries if you don't want to create your own. You just need to Google it :)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-table

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-easy-table

https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/